# Exec JS after flag ajax result

Tags: 7, ajax, flags

In my portal I need to use "flags" module to create a simil twitter "follow/unfollow". I have installed and configurated this module. All works, via AJAX too.

Now I need to exec some other JS function after that the flag module has completed his call. I think that I need to add (on the backend) some "commands" before flags return "commands" to execute in the frontend.

How I can I do this ?

Thanks, M.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/subscriptions check out this module also, may be what you are trying to implement.

Comment: Beebee: thanks but in my project I use flags for other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is API https://www.drupal.org/node/336122

The two events

The flagGlobalAfterLinkUpdate event

This event is triggered immediately after a flag link has been updated. (Flag links appear in two flavors: "Bookmark this!" and "Unbookmark this!", and when we speak of "update" we mean this change in appearance).

The flagGlobalBeforeLinkUpdate event

This event is triggered just before a flag link is updated. As will be explained later, the existence of this event is for cosmetic reasons only: it allows us to carry out actions while the throbber () is still visible.

```
$(document).bind('flagGlobalAfterLinkUpdate', function(event, data) {
  alert('Object #' + data.contentId + ' (of type ' +
    data.contentType + ') has been ' + data.flagStatus +
    ' using flag "' + data.flagName + '"');
});
```